# Displaying current & total page number N(N)

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript,so forgive my silly mistakes in advance.

I have a requirement where I have to print current and total page number excluding even pages which are blank.
Example : For 5 page long document,it should display like:
1(3)

2(3)

3(3)

Any sort of info is welcome since I am in dire need of this code to work.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var current_page=0 ;
var total_pages=0;


if((current_page<total_pages)||(current_page=total_pages))
{
    current_page++;
        if(current_page % 2!==0)
        {
            total_pages++;

        }
}
```

Also, this one too doesn't worked :(

```
var temp = (this.pageNum) + "(" + (this.numPages) + ")" ;
```

Comment: Use `==` or `===` for comparison in `if` condition

Comment: Well, I don't think that would solve, does it? @Tushar

Comment: Any time, you always have both as 0.

Comment: @Tushar You do have a point. Sorry! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar That wont solve the issue, but that's also an issue

Comment: @Tushar You **have** a point there.

Answer (score 2):

You have a logical error here:

```
current_page = total_pages // Note single = symbol between.
```

You are assigning instead of comparing. Please use `==` to compare:

```
current_page == total_pages
```

Or `===` for strict comparison as the type of both the variables is same.

Answer (score 0):

Does that help?

```
function (totalPages, currentPage)
{
    if (currentPage%2==1) return "";
    var tp = parseInt(totalPages/2+1);
    var cp = parseInt(currentPage/2+1);
    return "" + cp + "(" + tp + ")";
}
```